# Aptget without networking

Tags: networking, apt, package-management

i had a accident and i removed network-manager package, now i cannot get network access or internet access to apt-get install it back and reconfig the internet
what should i do? download the DVD and add a new source ?

Comment: Boot from Live USB, download the .deb and install it in your system

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is this:

**NOTE** Replace "wlan0" in all commands with your wireless interface found by running iwconfig

1. Open Terminal
2. Type "wpa_passphrase "YourNetworkSSIDHere" YourNetworkPasswordHere > ~/wpa_supplicant.conf" without quotes
3. Type "wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c~/wpa_supplicant.conf" without quotes
4. In new terminal tab, type: "dhclient wlan0" without quotes.
5. In another new terminal tab (unless it allows a new command after dhclient) type: "sudo apt-get install network-manager" for the old network connection, or "sudo apt-get install indicator-network" for the upcoming one.

Badabing badaboom!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your network with the commands [`ifconfig`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ifconfig) and [`iwconfig`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iwconfig) (iwconfig is dedicated for wireless interfaces) even without network manager.